# Connection custom code to odoo module

Tags: javascript, html, odoo

I created submenu item as submenu.xml in odoo'view folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
  <menuitem
    id="energy_saving_program_program_passport"
    name="name"
    parent="energy_saving_program.energy_saving_program_menu"
    sequence="405"
  />
</odoo>
```

So how to put my custom html and js code into this submenu tab?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do and what you have tried ?

Answer (score -1):

You can create your html or js code within that file like this.. For that you need to add inline js or inline html.

```
<menuitem>
   <html>for html code</html> or <script>for javascript</script>
</menuitem>
```

Apart from that another way is that you can define after your `<menuitem>` tag like this..

```
<menuitem>
</menuitem>
<script>Here you have to give particular element like in your case you can give id name by "#id" and after this your function</script>
```

Another way is you have to create another file for script in that file just give reference of your like here as a reference you can give id of your menu.
If you create a new file for this then don't forgot to add new js file in xml .